# Batch process photoshop layer with each saved layer having a specific filename

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, batch-processing

I have a layer that is a 250x250px circle.

I have an action set up to duplicate this circle layer and reduce the size by 99.2% (-2px).

I now need to be able to save this layer as a png file with the filename specific to the dimension of each layer - ie circle_248x248.png , circle_246x246.png and so on...

I can batch save but the tricky bit is making it save with the filename specific to the dimension of the layer..

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Adobe ExtendScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) to give you more control over the script and name the files programmatically. There is no way to do this with Actions.

You could use the GD library if you have access to a PHP server and write a simple script to create all your images, since it's such a simple operation.

```
for($i = 250; $i > 100; $i = $i - 2) {
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor($i, $i); 
  imageantialias($im, true);
  $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 
  $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
  imagefilltoborder($im, 0, 0, $white, $white);
  imagefilledellipse($im, $i/2, $i/2, $i, $i, $black);
  imagepng($im, "circle_".$i."x".$i.".png);
}
```

Sorry to immediately take the problem out of Photoshop, but this *is* stackoverflow...

Comment: That fantastic thanks for the help Matt, looks like you've saved me a lot of time and uneeded effort on this!